# How is working binary operation and boolean conversion?

Tags: c#, binary

I have this code :

```
int flags = some integer value;

compte.actif = !Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0002);
```

It is working very well the problem is I don't really understand how it s working..
The `&` operation is a bitwise AND I assume so Imagine 110110 & 000010 I assume it will result 001011 (maybe i'm wrong from here). The goal is to check if the 2's bit in the first term is filled. So in this case it is true.

I don't really understand How it can be converted in boolean..

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise and of 110110 & 000010 is 000010.

The `ToBoolean` [looks for a non-zero value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0b8dwce.aspx), so basically, this code checks that `flags` **has** the 2nd bit set, then negates it (`!`). So it is checking "is the 2nd bit clear".

A more traditional test there might be:

```
compte.actif = (flags & 0x02) == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise AND operation will give you an integer containing bits that were set on both numbers. I.e. 0b110011 & 0b010100 yields 0b010000.
The exclamation mark switches the boolean, causing true only of the 2nd bit is NOT set.